# What is the complexity order of Kalman rank condition?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, computational-complexity, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Does computing the Kalman rank condition of an integer matrix have complexity polynomial in the size of the input? if yes what is the order of complexity?

For a discrete-time linear state-space system, the state equation is

$$ x(k+1) = Ax(k) + Bu(k) $$

where $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix and $B$ is $n\times m$ matrix, the test of controllability is that the $n\times nm$ matrix $C$ which is in the blow :

\begin{bmatrix}B&AB&A^{2}B&\cdots &A^{n-1}B\end{bmatrix}

has full row rank. it is the Kalman rank condition to test controllability. but what is the computational complexity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the calculation of $AB,\cdots,A^{n-1}B$, the complexity is $O(n.n^2m)$. For the calculation of the rank, the complexity is $O(n^2.nm)$.

Finally , the total complexity is $O(n^3m)$.